How to add filters in Webflow

Select the Collection list you want to filter.

Go to the Settings panel.

Add a Filter under Collection list settings by clicking on the plus (+) sign.

Select the field you want to filter by in the first dropdown.

Choose a rule in the second field.

Specify a value if needed.

Click Save.


enter image description here
How to add filters in the Collection list.
